# Not Getting the current location inTextView

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to set current location in TextView. I tried some tutorials but its not worked.

gave all the permission in manifest.

Here my complete code:-

```
    package com.example.sachin.gps_currentlocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetCurrentGPSLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String mprovider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.current_gps_loaction);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        mprovider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (mprovider != null && !mprovider.equals("")) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mprovider);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mprovider, 15000, 1, this);

            if (location != null)
                onLocationChanged(location);
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location Provider Found Check Your Code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView longitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        longitude.setText("Current Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());
        latitude.setText("Current Latitude:" + location.getLatitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Here manifest

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sachin.gps_currentlocation">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".GetCurrentGPSLocation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

I tried many tutorails but non of these are giving me a location.. please suggest some required things for this...

Comment: you are not getting the current location ? or you are getting the current location but trying to show that in textview ?

Comment: no i didn't getting the current location

Comment: Did u enable location services in your device?

Comment: yes... and i tried in both emulator and phone

Comment: @user6880336 Are u testing it in marshamallow device or pre marshmallow?

Comment: marshmallow device

Comment: Can u check did u enable location permission in app settings

Comment: @user6880336 and add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> in manifest

Comment: its working thank you very much

Comment: @user6880336 I think yesterday u have posted same question as I remember I told you to handle the permission  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }. Don't just return; handle if permission not given in app

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on marshmallow device then you have give first dynamic permission

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
           if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
               // TODO: Consider calling
               ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                       PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
           } else {
                tv.setText("here yourcode");

            }
       } else {
           tv.setText("here yourcode");
       }
}


 @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
       super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       switch (requestCode) {
           case PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION: {
               if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   // permission was granted
                    tv.setText("yourcode");
               } else {
                   // permission denied
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Request not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
               break;


           }
       }
   }
```

above is code for dynamic permission for location. And this was work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This snip of code works with googleMaps so you can implement this logic:

```
public Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    //put handler in to recieve message object with long/lat from onLocationChanged 
    //to enable smoothly location changing in your TextView
    handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            Double long = msg.getData().getDouble("longitude");
            Double lat = msg.getData().getDouble("latitude");

            String myLocation = String.valueOf(long) + " " + String.valueOf(lat);

            textView.setText(myLocation);
        }
    };
}
```

And here is an example of your onLocationChanged method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Double longitude  = location.getLongitude();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putDouble("latitude", latitude);
            bundle.putDouble("longitude", longitude);

            Message message = new Message();
            message.setData(bundle);

            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Have a nice coding.